# Admob in iPhone with Tabbar and TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, admob, ads-api, uitabview

I'm having tab bar with 5 buttons. Out of 5 tabs, 2 are table views which uses navigation controller for showing sub views on click of cell.
Above the tab bar, in each view I left some space for ads using "Admob".
I'm adding ads using IB.
But its giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS when its reaching "adMobAd = [AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self];" in AdViewController.m

I'm using following lines of code to add views to tab bar view. In my code, I just added ads to LatestNews only. Can some one help me out of this problem.

```
UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

// create tab bar controller and array to hold the view controllers
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

// setup the first view controller (Root view controller)
LatestNews* latestNewsController;
latestNewsController = [[LatestNews alloc] initWithTabBar];



 // create the nav controller and add the root view controller as its first view
  localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:latestNewsController];

  // add the new nav controller (with the root view controller inside it)
  // to the array of controllers
  [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

  // release since we are done with this for now
  [localNavigationController release];
  [latestNewsController release];

  // setup the second view controller just like the first
  Forums* forumsController;
  forumsController = [[Forums alloc] initWithTabBar];

  localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:forumsController];
  [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
  [localNavigationController release];
  [forumsController release];

 RecipeList* recipesController = [[RecipeList alloc] initWithTabBar];
 localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:recipesController];
 [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
 [localNavigationController release];
 [recipesController release];

 //Setup Connect view
 Connect* cnt = [[Connect alloc] initWithTabBar];
 [localControllersArray addObject:cnt];
 [cnt release];

 //Setup Subscribe View
 Subscribe* scribe = [[Subscribe alloc] initWithTabBar];
 [localControllersArray addObject:scribe];
 [scribe release];

  // load up our tab bar controller with the view controllers
  tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

  [localControllersArray release];
  [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You state that your application is crashing when you access the AdMobView, yet none of the above code shows how you set up this view.  Without that, we can't give you specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is likely because the ad view is set to nil in the controller.

Check that you've attached the AdMob view in Interface Builder to a view attribute in your view controller.